# Please Explain Why this code's result is 18

Tags: php

Can anyone explain...

Why this code's result is 18

```
<?php echo 3+"15%"+"$25";  ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: what's the desired result? sounds like homework.

Comment: I just checking my knowledge. And confused here that why this code's result is 18.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the way that php parses strings to numbers. "15%" is 15 and "$25" is 0. You can check the specifics in the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: @GyandeepSharma You should then mark the answer as accepted, so that other users benefit from this answer too.